# Cargar Imagen desde un picturebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy haciendo un programa de webcams y no puedo guardar la imagen de la webcam, hasta ahorita solo me aparece la cámara en un picturebox, y tengo un picturebox2 donde capturo la imagen, pero necesito guardar esa imagen en una carpeta, ya sea en escritorio o donde sea, y no se como hacerlo!!

Alguien que me ayude, tengo mi botón de guardar y necesito que al presionar ese botón se abra la ventana para guardar la imagen.

Answer (score 3):

Entiendo que si se abre el dialog para grabar es porque usas el `SaveFileDialog`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg"  ;
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Image File";

    if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.IO.FileStream fs = (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();

        pictureBox1.Image.Save(fs, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Tambien podrias usar el nombre del archivo

```
if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   pictureBox1.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias!!! Ya me funciona

Answer (score 1):

Pruebe este:

```
string miCarpeta = @"C:\Imaginas\Imagina42.jpg";
pictureBox1.Image.Save(miCarpeta, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: No me sale, tira un error en la segunda linea, te adjuntare una imagen abajo

Comment: Cual es el error?

Comment: @SergioRivera  recuerda que debes especificar la ruta con el nombre del archivo incluido como ser:  C:\Dibujos\nombrearchivo.jpg

Comment: Si, ya me funciona, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score -2):

Puedo añadir a una imagen cargada en un picturebox (factura, documento), datos contenidos en label o textbox, encima de la imagen y guardarlos juntos.

Gracias.

Pedro Nuñez